# Why didn't Naruto help Nagato?

Tags: naruto

When Nagato reanimated everyone who died in the village, Katsuyu was with him.

Couldn't Naruto use Katsuyu to help Nagato, or is it for some other reason?

Comment: Can you please word this more clearly?

Comment: That small slug could not save Pain lol

Comment: please rephrase your question, it is very unclear

Comment: Or can you show us references, images or proof that can support your question?

Comment: I think you mean either: 1. Naruto could have donated his chakra to Nagato, like he did to Chiyo in the Kazekage rescue arc, and that could have somehow saved him from the after-effects of Rinne Tensei. OR 2. Katsuyu could have saved Nagato similar to how she did to the others when Nagato used the Shinra Tensei earlier. NOTE: I am neither confirming nor denying either is possible, just trying to clarify the question for the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When Naruto returned to Konoha, Tsunade ordered one of its smaller
>   clones to stay in Naruto's pocket and keep him informed of Pain's
>   abilities. [naruto wikia](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Katsuyu)

First and foremost, Tsunade didn't intend to heal Pain from the start but just wanted to located naruto instead. Even if Katsuyu implied to do, I think smaller clone are smaller in ability like healing and other. Probably, the Katsuyu in Naruto's pocket can't have enough chakra to heal Pain.

> Furthermore, Katsuyu's clones are extremely resistant to high amounts
>   of damage, as seen during Invasion of Pain Arc. Katsuyu is also able
>   to absorb people into its body, thus protecting them from physical
>   impacts like the large-scale Shinra Tensei using its own high
>   durability. [naruto wikia](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Katsuyu)

Aside from that , Katsuyu seem to absorb physical impacts only and it can't do nothing to chakra overexertion from as far as I watched.

Answer (score 0):

As revealed by later chapters, *Gedo: Rinne Tensei* is a **Tensei Ninjutsu**, meaning, it transfers the life-force of the user onto another (or others).

> This was confirmed by Obito by saying that to revive Madara, he would need to throw his life away.

No amount of chakra in the world could have saved Nagato, just like Naruto's chakra didn't save Chiyo back then (only helped her complete the technique).

Answer (score 0):

1st, Chakra IS Life Force

2nd Nagato didn't have enough chakra at the time to revive the whole village as stated in Chapter 449

While Nagato died, it should be noted that it was when he revived a whole bunch of people, and when Obito said he die if used it on Madara (chapter 614) who was dead for over 17 yrs, both were extreme cases..... it can be assumed that if you don't have enough chakra, then you'd die if you used Rinne Tensei and the more extreme the case but you could survive if you had enough chakra....

going there, that could mean that the longer the person is dead, the more chakra it'll take to revive them, so if he took time to rest, then it'd have taken even more chakra to revive each person

then Nagato did his jutsu before Naruto knew what was going on so once the jutsu was done and all, then Naruto couldn't help him

while Naruto was able to help Chiyo, Pein's revival jutsu seemed to be even shorter than Chiyo's and Naruto didn't have much of Katsuya and Tsunade used up almost all her chakra so she couldn't transfer chakra to Nagato even if she wanted to...

Comment: Chakra is most certainly **not** life force. Chakra is a combination between Physical Energy (Yang == Life force) and Spiritual Energy (Yin == Comes from training). Some techniques, such as the Rinne Tensei, drain the life-force from the user. That's in addition to the chakra requirement.